# Use custom fonts in xamarin forms

Tags: fonts, xamarin.forms

I want to use custom font in `xaml` file in xamarinforms on the portable folder(not iOS and android) that get an output for all of this platform.

Comment: did you try to google it?

Answer (score 6):

1. Add fonts into your platforms as explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Using_a_Custom_Font).
2. Create a font style that reflects on your platform like:

   ```
       <OnPlatform x:Key="NormalFont" x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                   iOS="Montserrat" Android="Montserrat"
                   WinPhone="Assets/Fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat"/>
   ```
3. use it with any of below options:

   - Direct using :
     `<Label Text="test" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}"/>`
   - Using With anonymous style (that affects all labels in your app):

     ```
     <Style TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource NormalFont}"/>
     </Style>
     ```
   - Use with named Style:

     ```
     <Style x:Key="TitleStyle" TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Boldfont}"/>
     </Style>

     <Label Text="Options" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}"/>
     ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want do implement this on your own, you can use the `CustomFontEffect` we added in the CommunityToolkit for Xamarin forms : https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/src

There is an example project added but overal usage is as follows:

```
<Label Text="Comic Sans is tha bomb!">
    <Label.Effects>
        <effects:CustomFontEffect FontPath="ComicSaaaaaans.ttf" FontFamilyName="Comic Sans MS" />
    </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

Comment: Broken Link, please modify.

Comment: Done, new link to the toolkit added

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add font file to PCL project and set is as embedded resource.
Then declare export font in assembly.cs file like given below

**[assembly: ExportFont("customFont.ttf", Alias="CustomFontName")]**

Consume it directly in label using alias name

```
<Label Text="This is custom font examaple" 
    FontFamily="CustomFontName" FontSize="50" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Hope it helps!