# Set custom fonts in custom View Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've created a custom view in a LinearLayout and declared a TextView

```
var headerControl = new TextView(Context);
```

but I want to set custom fonts. I have the fonts in a file, but I can't set them. Do you know how to set custom fonts in a custom view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom fonts in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824040/use-custom-fonts-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @SérgioReis the use of 'Context' above suggests it's not a forms project, rather a Xamarin native. I don't think that question you linked, adequately provides an answer. There is likely a duplicate out there somewhere though.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt hmm do have to agree with you, my bad

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to set custom fonts. I have the fonts in a file, but I can't set them. Do you know how to set custom fonts in a custom view?

You can follow the below steps to set the custom fonts to TextView:

1. If your targeting API level is below 26(android 8.0) you need to install `Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Util` through Nuget Package first.
2. Create a `font` folder under your `Resources` folder and add your font files to this folder, make sure they are added as `AndroidResource`:

[image]

3. In codes:

   ```
   tvTest = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvTest);
   Typeface typeface= ResourcesCompat.GetFont(this, Resource.Font.linoleo_script);
   tvTest.Typeface = typeface;
   ```